# Enable email to salesforce in scratch org definition file

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org-definition-file

I need to enable this function as part of the CI, soemthing like this:

```
"emailSettings": {
        "enableEmailToSalesforce": true
    }
```

But this isn't the right option, i'm having an error to create the scratch org with this option, so I'm assuming is incorrect.
Is there any list with detailed options to check Settings option in scratch org def file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, just found the answer in the documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailadministrationsettings.htm

The correct option is:

```
"emailAdministrationSettings": {
        "enableEmailToSalesforce": true
    }
```